# keep me logged in for windows + forms login

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, authentication

I want the functionality of Facebook and GMail to be implemented in my ASP.NET application.

I use a combination of windows and forms login and all of this is working just fine.

I have a login page which has the following code:

```
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    IntPtr token;
    IntPtr tokenDuplicate;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
        String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);


protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if (LogonUserA(userName, Domain.Text, Password.Text, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) == 0)
            {
                BadCredentials.Visible = true;
                BadCredentials.Text = "Not A Valid User";
                Global.logger.Info("LogonUserA failed with GetLastWin32Error code =" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return;
            }
            Global.logger.Info("LogonUserA is sucessful");


                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) == 0)
                {
                    BadCredentials.Visible = true;
                    BadCredentials.Text = "Internal Error: DuplicateToken failed";
                    return;
                }

Session["TokenDuplicate"] = tokenDuplicate;
            if (new GUIUtility().impersonateValidUser(Session) == false)
            {
                BadCredentials.Visible = true;
                BadCredentials.Text = "Impersonation failed";
                return;
            }

if (GUIUtility.IsUserPartOfWindowsGroup(compUsrNameForEncryption, adminGroupName) == true)
            {
                // The user is Instance Admin

                BadCredentials.Visible = false;


            }
// Create the authentication ticket
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,                          // version
                                       UserName.Text,           // user name
                                       DateTime.Now,               // creation
                                       DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),// Expiration
                                       false,                      // Persistent 
                                       role);         // User data

        // Now encrypt the ticket.
        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        // Create a cookie and add the encrypted ticket to the
        // cookie as data.
        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);            

        //authCookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;

        // Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
        //Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(UserName.Text, false));
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        // Company Admin has logged on

}
```

This is what is there on my web.config which can be useful:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" name="GUI" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30" path="/">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30"/>

    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
  -->
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Login.aspx">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
```

This code in my global.ascx:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName.ToString();
            HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
            if (null != authCookie)
            {
                authCookie.Secure = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Global.logger.Error("Application_BeginRequest: Exception: " + ex);
        }
    }

     protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        // Extract the forms authentication cookie

        string redirectSecureUrl = Request.Url.ToString();

        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName.ToString();
        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];


        if (null == authCookie)
        {

            // There is no authentication cookie.
            return;
        }

        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
        try
        {
            authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Global.logger.Error("Application_AuthenticateRequest: Exception: " + ex);

            return;
        }

        if (null == authTicket)
        {
            // Cookie failed to decrypt.
            return;
        }

        // When the ticket was created, the UserData property was assigned a
        // pipe delimited string of role names.
        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });

        // Create an Identity object
        FormsIdentity id = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);

        // This principal will flow throughout the request.
        GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
        // Attach the new principal object to the current HttpContext object
        Context.User = principal;
    }
```

What happens if I make the persistent cookie true instead of false?

Thanks.

Comment: i try changing it to false still no change in behaviour.. when open the login page and log in once and then open a new window of that browser and try to open the website,, i dont need to login again.. but when i close all the windows and open the app again i come back to the login screen.

Comment: so instead,, i want it keep logging in without asking him to login again unless i press signout

Comment: You seem to be doing an awful lot of work that the framework could be doing for you instead. Set the cookie to persistant and it will stop being session only and will last for the amount of time you set, regardless of whether you open and close your browser.

Comment: @Simon, why don't you post that as an answer instead of a comment so they can mark it as the correct answer, if it is.

Answer (score 1):

For reference...

If you use true a cookie with a fixed expiry date will be created rather than a session only cookie. The cookie & therefore the authentication ticket will then survive the browser being closed.

Simon

Comment: can u point me to an example or some reference.. it will be quiet helpful

Comment: .Net reference for creating a durable cookie -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce(v=VS.90).aspx